# J-1 2-year requirement waiver

Tags: usa, j-visa

Several years ago, I was sponsored to receive a J-1 visa via government funding. I was subsequently subject to the two year home residency requirement, so I went home for a few years satisfying that requirement.

Afterwards, I received another J-1 visa but I funded this one personally. Since then, I met my fiance and wish to stay in the US, so I'm applying for a waiver to the two year requirement. However, during the application process, it asks for copies of all forms DS-2019. Does this mean that I should include all such forms I've ever received, or just the ones relevant to my J-1s whose 2 year requirement is not already satisfied?

Also should I checkmark the box that asks whether any of my J-1s received government funding? I'm afraid that if I checkmark that box, they will look at it, and immediately throw out my waiver application, thinking that I am subject to the requirement because I received government funding for my earlier J-1. Then there would be no way to appeal, so I feel doing so is risky

Similarly, it asks for pictures of the J-1 Visa pages for when I entered the US? Should I include the old already served ones?

Comment: When you say that you funded your second J1 personally, do you mean to say that that second J1 doesn't have a 2-year home residency requirement? If it doesn't, then why would you be applying for a waiver? What would you be "waiving"?

Comment: I echo @user102008's comment, and I also want to ask why you think revealing government funding would lead to automatic rejection of the waiver application when the thing being waived is something that arises when there is government funding?  Anyway, you have to check it, because if you don't you might be found *permanently inadmissible* for misrepresentation ([8 USC 1182(a)(6)(C)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/8/1182#a_6_C).  Also, I think you have to get married before you can apply for the waiver, but user102008 probably knows more about this than I do.

Comment: Since I personally funded it, there shouldn't be a two year requirement. However, because of the way the Chinese government handles the "skills list" everybody gets marked with the requirement, and then they later must acquire a no objection statement from the Chinese embassy. I've lately  been thinking along the same line as @phoog regarding checking the box. The confusion is primarily just the scope of phrases like "all forms DS-2019"

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken, but I think No Objection Statements are not issued when government funding is provided, but that *shouldn't* be a problem in my case since the time has already been served.